# React Router v4.0 - Redirect to a page outside of Router scope

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'd like to be able to navigate to a home page outside of "subpage" defined in a < Router >. Here's my component.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import { Search } from './page/Search';
import { Quote } from './page/Quote';

export class MainContent extends React.Component<{}, {}> {    
    redirectToHomepage(){
        // something.push('/')
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="main">
                <button onClick={this.redirectToHomepage}>
                    Back Home
                </button>
                <Router>
                    <div>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={Search} />
                        <Route path="/quote" component={Quote} />
                    </div>
                </Router>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default MainContent;
```

By clicking on a button, I'd like to return to a homepage. Inside the { Search } component, I'm able to go to a page using `this.props.history.push('/quote');`

But how can I do it from the MainConent Component?

Thank you

Comment: I got the same problem, `browserHistory` is not available anymore as import from `react-router`

Answer (score 1):

You can import the browserHistory and use the 'push' method i think:

```
import { browserHistory }  from 'react-router;

redirectToHomepage(){
    browserHistory.push('/home');
}
```

Update react-router 4:
Now you need to use Redirect component from 'react-router-dom', some like:

```
render() {
  render (
    { this.props.authenticated ? 
      (<Redirect to={{ pathname: '/', state: { from: this.props.location }}} />) :
      (<div> Content</div>)}
  )
}
```

Comment: is it possible using only react-router-dom ? I don't have react-router installed

Comment: @MariánZekeŠedaj i think no, react-router-dom only export dom elements

Comment: browserHistory is not avai anymore in react router v4+

Comment: Yep, now you should use <Redirect to="path_name" />

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Link and IndexLink components from react router

```
var {Link, IndexLink} = require('react-router');

.....
<IndexLink to="/" activeClassName="active">Home Page</IndexLink>
.....
```

Style this how you please or combine it with a button and you could use this approach.
Cheers! Hope it helped

Comment: Thank you but I don't want to use Link because the use-case is slightly different, i need to be able to call it programatically

Answer (score 0):

First you should create a history and pass it to the `<Router>`.

In your example:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

// new import
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

import { Search } from './page/Search';
import { Quote } from './page/Quote';

export const history = createBrowserHistory();

export class MainContent extends React.Component<{}, {}> {    
    redirectToHomepage(){
        history.replace('/myfancypage');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="main">
                <button onClick={this.redirectToHomepage}>
                    Back Home
                </button>
                <Route history={history}>
                    <div>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={Search} />
                        <Route path="/quote" component={Quote} />
                    </div>
                </Router>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default MainContent;
```

You can then also call `history.replace('/myfancypage')` inside your main component as well as from anywhere where you do `import {history} from 'path-to-maincontent-file.js'`.

Also [check the router v4 docs here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router)

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with nested routes in react-router-dom (v4) I tend to structure the paths/components as such:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';


const Quote = () => (
    <h1>Kick butt and chew bubble gum</h1>
);

const OtherQuote = () => (
    <h1>“Be yourself; everyone else is already taken.”― Oscar Wilde</h1>
);


export class SubPage extends React.Component {

    redirectToHomepage = () => {
        this.props.history.push('/')
    };


    render() {
        return (
            <div id="main">
                <button onClick={this.redirectToHomepage}>
                    Back Home
                </button>
                <div>
                    <Route path="/quote" component={Quote} />
                    <Route path="/otherQuote" component={OtherQuote} />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


export class ReactRouterNesting extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <Route path="/" component={SubPage}/>
                </div>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}
```

Subpage will be rendered each time, as it will always match the '/' route, but the remaining content of the page is based on the path. There is no need for nesting the Router component within the subpage, and keeping the routes nested in this way, and not within multiple routers, will pass the history through props, and allow you to push to history through props.

Hope this helps and good luck!